# the rate of change of pressure

Tags: calculus

The atmospheric pressure at sea level is approximately $14.7$ psi. The pressure changes as altitude increases and can be calculated using the relation $P(h) = 14.7\cdot e^{-0.21 h}$, where $P$ is pressure in psi and $h$ is altitude above sea level in miles.

Find an expression for the rate of change of pressure as altitude changes and estimate the rate of change in Denver, CO ($h = 1$ mile).

Comment: What have you tried?  You are supposed to take the derivative of pressure with respect to $h$ and substitute in the given $h$.

Answer (score 1):

Take the derivative of $P(h)$
$$P’(h)=14.7\times -0.21 e^{-0.21h}$$
then substitute $h$ with the $h$ of Denver.
You will get your answer.
I don’t know if you have ever tried to solve this simple question...